# How to Develop Google TV apps Using Android

Tags: android, google-tv

I am developing android application for Google TV.
I am very new to Google TV development using Android SDK.

I have configured my Linux machine with the Google TV + Android development environment with eclipse.
So please can anyone share the documentation for Google TV App development.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google TV Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_demo_samples)

**Note:** The Android Developers Guide is the complete and definitive documentation for Android applications. Remember to consult it as you work on your Google TV applications.